# how to integrate $\int x^ae^xdx$ where a is non-integer

Tags: integration

It's not hard to evaluate $\int x^ne^xdx$ if n is integer, but how to do it if n is non-integer ?

Comment: There is not a closed-form formula for this anti-derivative in terms of what you would call "elementary functions."  But the story doesn't end there.  Google "Euler Gamma Function."

Comment: Even better, the incomplete Gamma functions.

Comment: Maple says $$\frac{x^a}{(-x)^a} a (\Gamma(a,-x) - \Gamma(a)) + x^a e^x$$

Answer (score 0):

By parts,

$$\int x^ne^x\,dx=x^ne^x-n\int x^{n-1}e^x\,dx
\\=x^ne^x-nx^{n-1}e^x+n(n-1)\int x^{n-1}e^x\,dx
\\=\cdots
\\=e^x\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k(n)_kx^{n-k}.$$

where $(n)_k$ denotes the falling factorial.

Unfortunately, this series diverges for all $x$.

Comment: it is clearly specified for $a$ non-integer.

Comment: @zwim: it is clear that this holds for non-integer $n$.